# call questa sim commands from SystemVerilog test bench

Tags: tcl, system-verilog, modelsim, questasim

I want to call questa sim commands like add wave ,add list, write list from my SystemVerilog test bench

```
task add_files_to_list();
add wave -position insertpoint  sim:/top/clk

add list sim:/top/clk 

write list -window .main_pane.list.interior.cs.body /home/simulation/top/example.lst

endtask
```

but the above doesn't work when i do from system verilog, i have to do i manually from tool.
is there any way to do it. or can i call a tcl script from my system verilog code.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
 mti_fli::mti_Cmd("command")
```

See /examples/systemverilog/dpi/cpackages/test.sv

Comment: can i call tcl file from system verilog ?

Comment: @Paebbels Please do.

Comment: @dave_59 Here is the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37933083/why-should-an-hdl-simulation-from-source-code-have-access-to-the-simulators-a

Comment: @user3627129 I think we are using script file for that commands, like run.sh which contain all that commands OP listed in *add_files_to_list*, to make testbench irrespective of tool, people mostly refer scripts instead of commands in code it self.